# How to make window.prompt fields required in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, window, prompt

I am taking input using window.prompt. There are three prompt one after another. I want to make every prompt box required like we do in form fields. Is there any way to achieve that facility in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can inspire from below code for every prompt:

```
let input = prompt('Do something?');
if (input === null || input.trim() === "") {
   // execute certain action
}
```

Comment: hey yes. I tired that. I am taking - let input = Number(prompt('Do something?')); converting into number and then checking. It gives "undefined" for number and also tired "input.toString().length" which is giving me 1 length each time (which is 0). It is taking 0 as input even when am keeping it blank.